# JavaFX repeat loop when transition ends

Tags: java, loops, javafx, transition, wait

I'm trying to perform the following loop:

1. Update some variables
2. Play a transition based on/representing the variables
3. Once the transition is done, go to 1

This repeats forever. I made it work with the following:

```
//Step 3
transition.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        doTheThing(); //Step 1, updates data
        transition.setToValue(data);
        transition.play(); // Step 2
    }
});

transition.play(); //Triggers first repeat
```

Of course, this is an endless recursive loop, which isn't a good idea. The problem is, I can't figure out how else to trigger the repeat once the transition finishes. I've tried using a loop:

```
while (1==1){
    doTheThing();
    transition.setToValue(data);
    transition.play();
}
```

But not only does this not wait for the transition (to be expected and not a problem for me), it doesn't play the transition at all, and the program is unresponsive. I've also tried this:

```
transition.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        ready = true;
    }
});
while (1==1){
    if (ready){
        ready = false;
        doTheThing();
        transition.setToValue();
        transition.play();
    }
}
```

But it acts the same as solution #2. I would prefer to not have a wait programmed in, but even if I did, I'm not sure how to make the loop wait before it repeats, without also stopping the transition from playing.

What can I do instead?

Comment: I don't think your first version creates infinite recursion. The `transition` necessarily encapsulates some threading, so the `play` method basically schedules the transition in a thread somewhere, and then immediately exits. Since it exits you are not retaining method calls on the stack. (@eckig's solution is preferred, though).

Comment: That would mean no stack overflow right? I left it running quite a while and wondered why it didn't break, I just assumed it was lightweight or something. Also, if this causes no errors, why is @eckig's solution preferred? (Not doubting that it is, just wondering why)

Comment: Yes, that would mean no stackoverflow. I prefer @eckig's solution because it's clearer what's happening. Since the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#play--) explicitly states that `play()` is an asynchronous call, I think your original code is fine, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a [`TimeLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) where you can specify the `cycleCount` which you can set to [`INDEFINITE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#INDEFINITE).

Example:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), ev -> {
    // TODO do something meaningful here
}));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll mark it accepted as soon as I get it working (which might take a while as I haven't used timelines before).